# "[Error] ld returned 1 exit status" постоянно, от разных реализаций функций, делающих скрин

Tags: c++, c, winapi, devc++

Понадобилась функция, делающая скриншот в программе и сохраняющая его в файл. Я нашёл несколько таких функций, но каждая (!) из них при добавлении в программу заставляет её выдавать при компиляции вот такую ошибку:

`C:\{папка_с_файлом.cpp}\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status`

Причём других ошибок нет, или я их исправляю. Обычно такая ошибка происходит, когда у меня код уже скомпилирован и запущен .exe, и я пытаюсь ещё раз его скомпилировать и запустить. Но, разумеется, я всё перепробовал, даже запускал код на другом компе (но тоже в Dev) - такая же ошибка.

Если убрать эту функцию, то код снова нормально работает. Подскажите, что делать?

Вот текущий код с одним из вариантов функции, делающий скриншот:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>//Ws2_32.lib
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>  //getch
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
//#include <sys/socket.h>
#define ever (;;)
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "GdiPlus.lib")

//Тут всякий другой код. Вообще, программа для работы с сетью (это клиент). 
//Но она даже не запускается, выдаёт ту ошибку.

using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus; 

static const GUID png = 
{ 0x557cf406, 0x1a04, 0x11d3, { 0x9a, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x1e, 0xf3, 0x2e } };


int PrtScr()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    HDC scrdc, memdc;
    HBITMAP membit;

    scrdc = GetDC(0);

    int Height, Width;
    Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);

    memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
    membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
    SelectObject(memdc, membit);

    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    HBITMAP hBitmap;
    hBitmap =(HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membit);
     Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);
     char PerMin[12];
     strcpy (PerMin,"screen.png" );
    bitmap.Save((WCHAR*)PerMin, &png,NULL);

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    return 0;
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////  



int main()
{

    printf ("OK1\n");
    getch();
    PrtScr();
    printf ("OK2\n");
    getch();    
    //Тут всякий иной код
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Полный лог сборки, думаю, поможет лучше понять что же у вас происходит.

Comment: А не забыли ли вы подлинковать Ws2_32.lib?

Comment: @VladD, а это разве может являться причиной? Ведь это библиотеки, которые относятся к советам, но никак не к получению скриншота

Comment: @Владимир: Ну, у вас же есть `#include <Winsock2.h>`, значит, может быть и где-то функции оттуда используются.

Comment: Столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Оказалось , что в секции private slots указан несуществующий обработчик события. Это стало возможным после переименования кнопки.

Answer (score 5):

`ld returned 1 exit status` обычно означает, что у Вас в коде есть недопустимые символы. Они могут там быть даже если их вроде и не видно, например, русская буква `е` от английской `e` на первый взгляд ничем не отличается. Обычно это результат копипасты. Так как функция небольшая, то самый простой вариант для Вас решить проблему - переписать ее (вернее, **всю** копипасту) руками.

**Update**
Так же, проблемой может быть неподключенная библиотека. Нужно посмотреть по списку подключенных заголовочных файлов, к каким библиотекам они относятся и в натсройках проекта добавить все отсутствующие библиотеки.

Проблемой может быть и какой-то неподключенный заголовочный файл. Тут надо смотреть по названиям используемых функций и искать заголовки, где они объявлены.

Comment: спасибо! Попробую! Правда, странно, что это случалось с несколькими разными реализациями этой функции, ну ладно, всякое бывает)

Comment: Может быть, виноват был самый первый вариант. Если вставляли в один и тот же файл, от него могло что-то остаться. Лучше, вообще говоря, попробовать в совсем новом файле. Еще (но, на мой взгляд,  менее вероятно) может быть, что виноват сайт, если примеры были с одного сайта, или браузер, которые добавили что-то лишнее в тексты.

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ, еще может быть проблема в том, что Вы какую-то необходимую библиотеку не подключили.

Comment: пробовал в разных файлах и на разных компьютерах (но в Dev), и с разных сайтов. На счёт библиотек - странно, а разве не выдаст ошибку о том, что что-то (тип, функция и т.д.) не описано? Если нужная библиотека или заголовочный файл не подключен? И ещё: у меня не проект, а просто программа отдельная, и настроек проекта у меня нет. Но, наверное, можно подключить библиотеки и в самой IDE. Я так понимаю, мне нужно заходить во все подключаемые файлы (которые относятся к функции скриншота) и искать все подключения, кончающиеся на .lib, и их подключать где-то в настройках IDE?

Comment: Нет, Вам нужно на MSDN найти описание каждого заголовочного файла или используемой функции и подключить в настройках проекта (или в командной строке при запуске линкера) библиотеки, указанные в описании.

Answer (score 2):

При неподключённой библиотеке или опечатке в определении метода линкер всегда указывает, какой именно метод неопределён. По его имени можно грепнуть, где он определяется и подлинковать либу.

Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой без какой-либо дополнительно информации от линкера, тоже долго чесал репу и искал опечатки, но в итоге заметил, что на диске, где собираюсь, мало места. Перенёс исходники на накопитель побольше - там сразу нормально слинковалось.
Возможно, решение проблемы AlfredBauer'ом связано с тем же, т.к. 32-битные бинарники занимают меньше места.

В общем, при недостатке места на этапе линковки может выводиться подобное сообщение без поясняющей информации.
Словил на CentOS 6.9, g++ 4.8.2, glibc 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

Решил такую проблему изменением режима компиляции с **х64** на **х32**. При этом, у меня были подключены дополнительные библиотеки(которые были скомпилированы MinGW), с которыми компилятор видимо не мог работать в таком режиме.